# Flutter Google Maps and Flutter Map simultaneous work

Tags: flutter, google-maps, openstreetmap, state-management

I am building an application where there will be google maps and `flutter_map` which uses Open Street. Now I want to be like at first my position will be set with marker on `google_maps` but there will be a button that will change my map to `flutter_map` and the marker will be places on the same place as it was in `google_maps` part. Even polylines if drawn then if changed from one map to another it will draw on the same place of the other map. How can I achieve it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unfortunately, this could be against Google Maps API's TOS. Can you check [3.2.3 Restrictions Against Misusing the Services. (e) No Use With Non-Google Maps](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/terms#:~:text=(e)%C2%A0No%20Use%20With%20Non%2DGoogle%20Maps)? For specifically says there: _"Customer will not use the Google Maps Core Services with or near a non-Google Map in a Customer Application."_

Comment: Thanks for the information. I will definitely check now.